# Should I omit vertex normals when there is no lighting calculations?

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization

I have an openGL program that doesn't use lighting or shading of any kind; the illusion of shadow is done completely through textures, since the meshes are low-poly.  Faces are not backculled, and I wouldn't use normal-mapping of course.

My question is, should I define the vertex normals anyway?  Would excluding them use fewer resources and speed rendering, or would excluding them negatively impact the performance/visuals in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, should I define the vertex normals anyway?

There is no need to, if they are not used.

> Would excluding them use fewer resources and speed rendering, or would excluding them negatively impact the performance/visuals in some way?

It definitively wouldn't impact the visuals if there are not used.

You do not mention if you use old fixed-function pipeline or the modern programmable pipeline. In the old fixed-function pipeline, the normals are *only* used for the lighting calculation. The have *nothing* to do with the face culling. The front/back sides are determined solely by the primitive winding order in screen space.

If you use the programmable pipeline, the normals are used for whatever you use them. The GL itself will not care at all about it.

So excluding them should result in less memory needed for the object to be stored. If rendereing actually gets faster is hard to predict. If the normals aren't used, they shouldn't even be fetched, no matter if they are provided or not. But caching will also have an impact here, so the improvement of not fetching them might not be noticeable at all.

Only if you are using immediate mode(`glBegin()`/`glEnd()`) to specify geometry (which you really should never ever do), excluding the normals will save you one gl function call per vertex, and this should give a significant improvement (but still will be orders of magnitude slower than using vertex arrays).

Answer (score 1):

If normals are not used for lighting, you don't need them (they are not used for back-face culling either).

The impact of performance is more about how this changes your vertex layout and resulting impact on pre-transform cache (assuming you have interleaved vertex format). Like on CPU's, GPU's fetch data in cache lines, and if without (or with) normals you get better alignment with cache lines, it can have an impact on the performance. For example if your vertex size is 32 bytes and removal of the normal gets it down to 20 bytes this will cause GPU fetching 2 cache lines for some vertices, while with 32 byte vertex format it's always fetches only one cache line. However, if your vertex size is 44 bytes and removal of normal gets it down to 32 bytes, then for sure it's an improvement (better alignment and less data).

However, this is quite a fine level optimization in the end and unlikely have any significant impact either way unless you are really pushing huge amount of geometry through the pipeline with very lightweight vertex/pixel shaders (e.g. shadow pass).